# Get id from database

Tags: database, users, id, customization

I need this ID to delete users from table. My plugin crate new table in DB when he is activate. All this code is in main.php, and in second.php i have only form that display my results.. and i include that second.php in my main.php.

Here is my code

```
   global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM TestTable" ); ?>

   <?php foreach ( $result as $print ): ?>
   <tr>
    <td><?php echo $print->id;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $print->ime;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $print->prezime;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $print->datum;?></td>

    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="<?php echo $print->id; ?>" >
    </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Now i have create one function for delete users. But i can't find way to get dinamic this ID. 
Here is function for delete

```
function awesome_delete($values) {
  global $wpdb;
  $wpdb->delete( 'TestTable', array( 'id' =>HERE I NEED IT ));

}

    function awesome_process_request () {
      if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {


        if (array_key_exists('delete', $_POST) && $_POST['delete'] == 'Delete') {
          return awesome_delete($_POST['check_list']);
        }
...
```

Here is code where i create my table

```
function my_plugin_create_table()
{
   global $wpdb;
   if($wpdb->get_var("show tables like TRR_Stats") != 'TRR_Stats')
   {
      $sql = "CREATE TABLE TestTable (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     ime varchar(50) NOT NULL,
     prezime varchar(50) NOT NULL,
     datum varchar(50) NOT NULL,
     UNIQUE KEY id (id)
     );";
      require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
      dbDelta($sql);
   }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Is there any reason passing in values as function parameters is not possible here? Why do you do `echo $ID = $print->id;` rather than `$ID = $print->id; echo $ID;`? Can you provide some context to your question? Such as what your TestTable is storing, where this code is located ( a theme? a plugin? ), when does this code run? etc

Comment: I make some changes.. I think that is now more clear what i want. Thank you.

Comment: People i still can't find answer... If someone can help, please .. write  :D